# Conditions for $\mathbb{E}|g(X_n)-g(X)|\to 0,g\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ when $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$ be a sequence of random variables.

Then for any $g\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ we have $|\mathbb{E}[g(X_n)]-\mathbb{E}[g(X)]|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Are there any sufficient and necessary conditions for the following convergence?

$\mathbb{E}[|g(X_n)-g(X)|]\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Many Thanks

Comment: No, convergence in distribution does not yield that kind of conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ and Lebesgue measure $P$. Consider $X_n = \omega$ and $X = 1- \omega$. They are $U[0,1]$. Suppose that $g(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and is bounded smooth and so on. Then $$E|g(X_n) - g(X)| = E|2\omega - 1| = E|2 X_1 - 1| = E|2U[0,1]-1| =$$
$$= E|U[-1,1]| = E|U[0,1]| = \frac12 > 0.$$ This example shows why bounded smooth functions $g$ and bounded r.v. $X_n$ are not good enough.

So, the answer is negative.

Very special case: if $X$ is a constant, then if follows that $X_n \to X$ in probability and thus $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in probability. As $g$ is bounded we have $E|g(X_n) - g(X)|$ by dominated convergence theorem.

So, the sufficient condition is "$X$ is a constant".

The problem with more general conditions is connected with the next fact: if we know the distribution of $X_n$ and do not know anything about $X$ except it's distribution, then there's no information about $(X_n, X)$ and hence about $E(|g(X_n) - g(X)|)$. There's a special case: when X is constant, and it's mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks very much.
Are there any known special cases when the wanted convergence hold?
e.g. when $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$ due to CLT?

Comment: @LBooliani, in CLT we know the distribution of $X_n$ and do not know anything about $X$ except it's distribution, which is normal. But information about distribution of $X$ doesn't give information about $(X_n, X)$ and hence about $E(|g(X_n) - g(X)|)$. There's a special case: when X is constant, and I made an addition about it.

Comment: Got it, thanks!